# Find the inverse of 789 in $\mathbb{Z^*}_{1234}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, inverse, integers

I'm confused on this homework question and not sure how to go about solving it.
Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks!

I need to find the inverse of 789 in (nonzero integers mod1234) $\mathbb{Z^*}_{1234}$

Comment: Do you know the euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd?

Comment: Yes, I know the euclidean algorithm. I have to use that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to solve the equation $$\overline{789}\cdot \overline{x}=\overline1$$ Now $$789\cdot x \equiv 1\pmod{1234}$$ Using Euclidean algorithm we found that $(789, 1234)=1$ so $1=-539\cdot 1234 + 843\cdot789$.That means $$x \equiv 843\pmod{1234} \implies \overline{x}=\overline{843}$$

Answer (score 0):

$1234=2\cdot 617$, hence it is enough to find the inverse of $789$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z})^*$ (trivial) and $\mathbb{Z}/(617\mathbb{Z})^*$. In terms of [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) We have:

$$ \frac{789}{617} = \{1; 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2\} $$
and
$$ \{1; 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1\} = \frac{289}{226} $$
with
$$ 789\cdot 226-617\cdot 289 = 1 $$
hence in $\mathbb{F}_{617}$ we have $789^{-1}=226$. By the Chinese remainder theorem,
$$ 789^{-1} \equiv 226+617 \equiv \color{red}{843}\pmod{1234}.$$